# Vue.js - How do I use this Boolean expression?

Tags: vuejs2

I've seen the following expressions being used inside this data set and was wondering how it will evaluate to true or false in Vue.js?

```
visibleIf: "{satisfaction-score} = 4"
```

In my example the first question is being hidden and I am not sure why?

```
test: [
    {
      name: "satisfaction-score",
      title: "How would you describe your experience with our product?",
      element: "Radio",
      value: 5,
      options: [
        { value: 5, text: "Fully satisfying" },
        { value: 4, text: "Generally satisfying" },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "what-would-make-you-more-satisfied",
      title: "What can we do to make your experience more satisfying?",
      element: "Input",
      value: "",
      visibleIf: "{satisfaction-score} = 4",
    },
  ],

<div v-for="t in test" :key="t.name">
  <component :is="t.element" :t="t" v-if="t.visibleIf"></component>
</div>
```

https://surveyjs.io/Documentation/Library?id=design-survey-create-a-multi-page-survey#configure-page-visibility

I am using surveyjs as inspiration because I don't know how to control the visibility of Object B depending on the option selected from Object A. Any ideas would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the first question is not rendered is because it doesnt have a `visibleIf` attribute. So in this case it will return `false`

You only render if `t.visibleIf` : `<component :is="t.element" :t="t" v-if="t.visibleIf"></component>`

In all cases where you have an attribute with this name, the question will render.

(With only one `=` you are assigning. If you want to check if satisfactionscore is above or below a value you should use `==` or preferably `===`. For this to actual work you need to make some changes. One way is to use backticks like this to make a check:

```
`${satisfaction-score} === 4`
```

satisfaction-score has to be set somewhere for this to work)